# End of line character confusion when using csv.dictreader

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am using csv.dictreader to return all stocks in a list of csv files who are 'True' in the Data row.

```
filename = glob.glob('*.csv')

susadict = {}
for file in filename: 
    with open(file, 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        susadict[file] = [row['Ticker'] for row in reader if row['Data'] == 'True']
```

This code only works for csv files that have an 'Â ' character in the last line, but doesn't work for files with 'åÊ' or  no chars, as of now only 2 of my 11 files have 'Â ' fields, so it is leaving 9 blank .

My expected output is to have all 11 working.

Comment: I get TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Seems you are on **2.7**, doesn't have such Parameter. Try [csv.Sniffer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer)

Comment: what would the format look like? Dont understand the documentation

Comment: You get `dialect`as result, use this in your `reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect)`.

Comment: but what goes in the dialect = , i have dialect = csv.Sniffer()

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: but what goes in the dialect = , i have dialect = csv.Sniffer()

**Follow the Example from the given Link: [csv.Sniffer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer)**
The `.seek(0)` after `Sniffer` is absolute necessary!

You could use one of the following, both are equivalent:

1. `reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect)`
2. `reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect=dialect)`

---

Your whole Example should look:

```
filename = glob.glob('*.csv')
susadict = {}
for file in filename: 
    # Python 3.x: with open(file) as csvfile:
    with open(file, 'rb') as csvfile:
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
        csvfile.seek(0)

        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect)
        susadict[file] = [row['Ticker'] for row in reader if row['Data'] == 'True']
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2 and Python:2.7.9 - csv:1.0***

Comment: I get ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: @thomas: [Edit] your Question and show **your** changed code and the full **Traceback**.